How do I represent a signal as the real part of complex exponential and find the value of complex amplitude & complex frequency?
Context:
I was solving some practice problems and came across this problem. I know the complex exponential is:
$$ s(t)=Ae^{i({\omega}t+{\phi})}{\Rightarrow}Ae^{i{\phi}}e^{i{\omega}t} $$
Where \$Ae^{i{\phi}}\$ would be the complex amplitude. The Eular representation of the above exponential would be:
$$ s(t)=Ae^{i({\omega}t+{\phi})}=A[cos({\omega}t+{\phi})+isin({\omega}t+{\phi})] $$
I also know we can represent cosine and sine signals in the Eular representation of complex exponential by using:
$$ {\{sin({\omega}t), cos({\omega}t)\}}=\{{\frac{{e^{(i{\omega}t)}}+{e^{(-i{\omega}t)}}}{2}},{\frac{{e^{(i{\omega}t)}}-{e^{(-i{\omega}t)}}}{2i}}\} $$
Problems:

I think you can re-write the first problem as: $$ v(t)=V*cos({\omega}t+{\phi})\Rightarrow 1*cos(5t+0{^\circ}) $$

This would give you Voltage=Amplitude=1 & Phase Angle = 0deg.
I then represented the cosine signal in the Eular representation of the complex exponential and I was able to get the and Frequency={5/2pi, -5/2pi}.
I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.


I couldn't solve for the second problem. Should I convert the sine signal into cosine by shifting it 90deg and then repeating the same steps as I did in first?





Yeah. Shift the sine to a cosine by subtracting 90 degrees (pi/2) for the ii case.

s represents the time-dependent bits. It's also the same as $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}$ operator. There are also the fixed bits, like phase and whatever part of amplitude doesn't vary with time. Complex multiplication includes both rotation and scaling (unlike real multiplication which is only scaling and doesn't include rotation.) Some of each part of that can be time-dependent and some isn't. So there are really four parts to complex multiplication when time is involved. Scaling independent of time, scaling dependent on time, rotation independent of time, and rotation dependent on time.

The $\exp\left(s t\right)$ part is only the time-dependent scaling and rotation pair of the four parts. It doesn't include rotation independent of time, which is what $\phi$ is. Since it is usually assumed that scaling doesn't vary with time, $\sigma=0$, so there is only $\omega$ related to time then -- rotation. So $\exp\left(s t\right)$ is often simplified to $\exp\left(j\omega t\right)$, instead. And to include phi you just write $\exp\left(j\omega t+j\phi\right)$. That's both the time-variant and time-invariant parts of rotation. You should use Eulers from there, I imagine.

Thank you for the brief explanation. "Shift the sine to a cosine by subtracting 90 degrees (pi/2) for the ii case", I think adding 90° would give us cos from sin since we're using the first one from sin(x+90)=cos(x) and cos(x-90)=sin(x). I tried doing it this way and I got sin(8t+45°+90°)=cos(8t+135°)=-cos(8t+45°). This in turn gives us Voltage=Amplitude=-1 and Phase Angle = 45°. It also gives me Frequency={8/2pi, -8/2pi}. I'm not sure if this entirely correct.

Use what works for you. But if I do a for x in np.arange(0,2*pi,0.01):(sin(x+pi/4)-cos(x-pi/4)).n() then it's all zeros for me.

Thanks & Yeah! You got zeros since sin(x+pi/4)-cos(x-pi/4) is 0 because both waves cancel each other out. You can think of it as shifting the sin wave forward by 45deg (horizontally) and shifting the cos wave backward by 45deg (also horizontally). They both meet at 45deg (since they're only apart by 90deg) and therefore cancel each other out.

If you have your answer, you may wish to select one. Or write your own and select it! Either way works! Or do you still have some unanswered details?

Yeah! Both answer's helped @periblepsis so I wasn't sure which one to select.
Edit: Should be selected now. Thank You!

Complex multiplication
Since you are interacting (good sign) here, I'll try and write something.
Complex multiplication performs both scaling and rotation in a single operation. Real number multiplication (incomplete system) provides only scaling.
For cases where time is involved (electronics!), there may be two parts in play. A part that isn't a function of time and a part that is a function of time.
Laplace uses s as a special transform variable with respect to t where \$s\$ is the operator \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\$. Technically, this could also be \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\$ or \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\$ for all anyone cares. But for electronics, time is key and so it's all about t.
Electronics
So, in electronics, there are things that depend on time and things that don't. Frequency depends on time, intimately. But the starting phase doesn't. It's just a constant.
This fact breaks up complex multiplication into two parts: (1) the scaling and rotation that is independent of time (like starting phase); and, (2) the scaling and rotation that depends upon time (like frequency.)
There are two ways to write this up for a voltage:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}&=\left[\text{constant and time-dependent scaling}\right]\left[\text{constant and time-dependent rotation}\right]
\\\\
&=\left[\text{time-independent scaling and rotation}\right]\left[\text{time-dependent scaling and rotation}\right]
\end{align*}$$
If we call \$A\$ the time-independent scalar for voltage and \$\sigma\,t\$ as the time-dependent scalar for voltage, and also call \$\phi\$ the time-independent rotation for voltage and \$\omega\,t\$ as the time-dependent rotation for voltage, then the above becomes:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}&=\left[\exp\left(\ln\left(A\right)+\sigma\right)\right]\left[\exp\left(j\left\{\phi+\omega\,t\right\}\right)\right]=A\exp\left(\sigma\right)\exp\left(j\left\{\phi+\omega\,t\right\}\right)
\\\\
&=\left[\exp\left(\ln\left(A\right)+j\,\phi\right)\right]\left[\exp\left(\left\{\sigma+j\,\omega\right\}t\right)\right]=A\exp\left(j\,\phi\right)\exp\left(s\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$
Where \$s=\sigma+j\,\omega\$.
Voltage sources don't scale over time. (Or, so we hope.) So \$\sigma=0\$. Therefore the above reduces to:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}&=A\exp\left(j\left\{\phi+\omega\,t\right\}\right)
\\\\
&=A\exp\left(j\,\phi\right)\exp\left(j\,\omega\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$
I'm sure you follow so far. Either way, we now have the same result:
$$\mathscr{Re}\left[\mathcal{V}\right]=A\cos\left(\omega\,t+\phi\right)=A\left[\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)\sin\left(\phi\right)\right]$$
However, none of that helps if you are looking to keep s in the picture. So let's back up:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}&=A\exp\left(j\,\phi\right)\exp\left(s\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$
All that's needed here is to expand the left two factors. Here, we find:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}&=\underbrace{A\left[cos\left(\phi\right)+j\,\sin\left(\phi\right)\right]}_V\exp\left(s\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$
This should make it pretty obvious what the complex value for \$V\$ is in your equation for \$V\exp\left(s\,t\right)\$.

I think you're correct with the time-independent and dependent analogy. If we take the complex exponential Ae^(i(ωt+ϕ)), keep s in the picture and expand everything out as Ae^(i(ωt+ϕ)) => A*e^(iϕ)*e^(iωt)*e^(σt). We indeed end up with four variables out of which A, e^(iϕ) are time-independent and e^(iωt), e^(σt) are time-dependent. It was mentioned that the complex amplitude is A*e^(iϕ) in the previous texts and it's called the phasor of the signal. It was also mentioned that complex frequency is the quantity multiplying t, I think here that would be e^t(σ+iω).

@Ayush Yes, that's the meaning of a phasor. It's just the fixed-length vector $A$, as rotated by the fixed angle $\phi$, at $t=0$. Also, since $s=\sigma+j,\omega$, your last expression is the same as $\exp\left(st\right)$. There's no difference.

Thank you! I'm able to understand this question more and I did get answers to all of them. I just need to practise more so I get better at it.

As this is a homework question, I'll answer with leading questions of my own:

Where did the 2pi come from in your Frequency answer? Could you define Frequency?
You give a definition for \$\sin (\omega t)\$; does it not suffice?  Better still, why not both: can you prove that your angle shift to \$\cos\$ is equivalent?

It seems to me, they're only asking for angular frequency \$\omega\$ in (1), but there might be other background in the chapter or lectures to better explain/support this choice.

To answer "Where did the 2pi come from in your Frequency answer? Could you define Frequency?", We can write cos(ωt)=[e^(iωt)+e^(−iωt)]/2 in it's Euler representation. We also know ω=2πf. In the first question ω=5 (because cos(5t)=cos(ωt)). If you now equate 5 for both ω and -ω from the Euler representation, you'll get 2πf=5 and 2πf=-5. This would give you f={5/2π, -5/2π}. I am not sure if this correct so I could be wrong.

To answer "You give a definition for sin(ωt); does it not suffice? Better still, why not both: can you prove that your angle shift to cos is equivalent?", I believe the angle shift should be equal since sin(x+90)=cos(x) and similarly cos(x-90)=sin(x). In the context of signals we have sin((ωt+ϕ)+90)=cos(ωt+ϕ) if we say x=ωt+ϕ. I'm not really sure of "It seems to me, they're only asking for angular frequency ω in (1), but there might be other background in the chapter or lectures to better explain/support this choice." since the question languages is a bit confusing.

Ok, then "frequency" is defined as cycles per second (1/s), not radians. The confusion is that we use "angular frequency" (it's still a frequency) for $\omega$ (rad/s), and without a definition, either one might be acceptable, or it might have been stipulated elsewhere.

Thanks Tim! In general I'll try to convert signals/waves to cosine and then solve it (because the question asks me to represent the signals in the real part of complex exponential which is cosine). I think you're right for frequency although I believe angular frequency and frequency are used interchangeably here. Since the question mentions complex frequency and ω is often used with signals. I'll just write both since they're very simple to figure out.
